# How can I make these wp_postmeta MySQL queries faster?

Tags: mysql

I'm making a search feature which updates available options when a selection is made on each of several dropdown menus.

Here are two mysql queries that are run to update two dropdown menus. With about 5000 products in the db, each query takes about 4s. How can I speed them up?

I tried combining them into a single query and grouping with PHP, but then options in the selected dropdown were unavailable if an option was cleared.

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.meta_value AS ship_id
FROM wp_posts a
JOIN wp_postmeta f ON ID = f.post_id
JOIN wp_postmeta g ON ID = g.post_id
JOIN wp_postmeta h ON ID = h.post_id
JOIN wp_postmeta d ON ID = d.post_id JOIN wp_postmeta i ON ID = i.post_id 
JOIN wp_postmeta l ON ID = l.post_id
WHERE post_type = 'product'
AND f.meta_key = 'first_start_date'
AND g.meta_key = 'last_start_date'
AND h.meta_key = 'product_group'
AND h.meta_value = 'cruises'
AND d.meta_key = 'destinationregion'
AND i.meta_key = 'destinationarea'
AND 'South America' IN (d.meta_value, i.meta_value)
AND (
        (CONCAT('2016', '01-01') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(f.meta_value, '%b %e, %Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(g.meta_value, '%b %e, %Y')) OR
        (STR_TO_DATE(f.meta_value, '%b %e, %Y') BETWEEN CONCAT('2016', '-01-01') AND CONCAT('2016' + 1, '-01-01'))
    )
AND l.meta_key = 'cruiseship'
ORDER BY l.meta_value ASC
```

-

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.meta_value AS destinationregion, i.meta_value AS destinationarea
FROM wp_posts a
JOIN wp_postmeta f ON ID = f.post_id
JOIN wp_postmeta g ON ID = g.post_id
JOIN wp_postmeta h ON ID = h.post_id
JOIN wp_postmeta d ON ID = d.post_id JOIN wp_postmeta i ON ID = i.post_id
WHERE post_type = 'product'
AND f.meta_key = 'first_start_date'
AND g.meta_key = 'last_start_date'
AND h.meta_key = 'product_group'
AND h.meta_value = 'cruises'
AND (
        (CONCAT('2016', '01-01') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(f.meta_value, '%b %e, %Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(g.meta_value, '%b %e, %Y')) OR
        (STR_TO_DATE(f.meta_value, '%b %e, %Y') BETWEEN CONCAT('2016', '-01-01') AND CONCAT('2016' + 1, '-01-01'))
    )
AND d.meta_key = 'destinationregion' AND i.meta_key = 'destinationarea'
ORDER BY destinationregion, destinationarea"
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide table structure, sample data and expected results.  Having a difficult time understanding currently.

Comment: The slow bit is the str_to_date part

Comment: Still 3.7s without that part. :(  wp_postmeta has 3 million rows...  The fewer repeated joins I have to do the better

Comment: MySQL loves joins - especially inner joins on indexed columns.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the aggregation form of the query:

The idea is:

```
select p.id,
       max(case when pm.meta_key = 'First_start_date' then pm.meta_value end) as first_start_date,
       max(case when pm.meta_key = 'last_start_date' then pm.meta_value end) as last_start_date,       
       max(case when pm.meta_key = 'product_group' then pm.meta_value end) as product_group,
       max(case when pm.meta_key = 'destinationregion' then pm.meta_value end) as destinationregion,
       max(case when pm.meta_key = 'destinationarea' then pm.meta_value end) as destinationarea,
       max(case when pm.meta_key = 'cruiseship' then pm.meta_value end) as cruiseship
from wp_posts p join
     wp_postmeta pm
     on pm.post_id = p.id
where p.post_type = 'product'
group by p.id ;
```

You can use a `having` clause or subquery for the specific filtering conditions on the values.

An index on `wp_posts(product, id)`, might help the query.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to think about how this works. Not sure if I'm doing this right, but I tried adding HAVING product_group = 'cruises' to the end and the query took 8s

Comment: @Dingalingalingalong . . . It is worth a try, but it might not be faster.

Comment: It won't be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Amend your data model so that the following works without any requirement for further functions:

`WHERE  f.meta_value < '2017-01-01' AND g.meta_value > '2016-01-01'`

I can't remember whether you can customise wp such that values can be arranged in tables according to data type, but if not, then at least store dates as correctly-formatted strings.

I assume that there's a compound index on (post_id,meta_key,meta_value)